# boostrap 4 datetimepicker in symfony form

Tags: jquery-ui, bootstrap-4, datetimepicker

I try in my symfony 5.1 form withh boostrap4 using jquery-ui datetimepicker for datetime input but I use in console error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function`. In template i have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and before closed body i have

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/admin.js') }}"></script>
```

and in admin.js I have

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $( "#new_application_date" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'});

});
```

whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in using jquery slim, this must be

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js">
```